# Unable to pass FB OAuth for my application

Tags: facebook

We faced with issue originally on the BB app. We stuck in browser whenever we use auth URL: 
[http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=publish_stream%2Coffline_access&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&response_type=token&display=touch&client_id=127229817336080](http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=publish_stream,offline_access&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token&display=touch&client_id=127229817336080)

Interesting what is wrong with the response because even desktop browser stuck.
We submitted issue to FB but still are looking for workaround. Any thoughts/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: If you give minus to the question please explain why

Comment: Can't start bounty. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure.  The "start a bounty" link appears below for me.  It doesn't look like you have any other active bounties (which might have prevented you from offering a bounty).  You might ask the question ("why can't I offer a bounty on this question", with hyperlink here) on meta.stackoverflow.com.  A moderator could help ... also there have been bugs in the past.  Maybe this is a bug?  Also, I'm interested in this issue, too, so if I get a chance this weekend, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whats wrong ?
i just installed your app with 2 extra permissions (posting as me & offline access token)
(just remember offline access token will be not available try to use long time tokens )

Comment: Did you install XMS from market? Did you see iPhone FB login page? What device and version of OS do you have?

Comment: Just checked. FB fixed their issue! Hurra!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong here, I just authed your app without problems....

Comment: I used Chrome 20.0, the callback went to a page that sayed nothing more then "succes!" But the app was added to my list of FB-Apps

Comment: Did you change user agent? Did you see page with two buttons "Install/Cancel" instead of permissions page? I've tried Firefox and the issue is there.

Comment: http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/6528/screenshotnjj.png
this is the screen I get, after that it asks for extended permissions after I accepted those I get a blank page with just: "Success" on it.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I don't know why it returns different page for Chrome. Because for Firefox (and BB browser) I get this one: http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/5735/firefoxeg.png

Comment: It could perhaps also have to do with my geographic location perhaps? (unless Chrome shows the same difference for you)

Answer (score 0):

Even we faced similar type of problems in authenticating our FB App. Authentication window use to hang up and nothing use to happen and symptoms were same as you are facing. Probably this may not be the answer to your problem but it might be worth knowing that FB SDK have such issues if your application runs on non-standard ports. The standard ports are 80 and 443. Once we started running our app on these ports the error was gone.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. What is the connection between FB SDK and my app connections? Do you provide your BB connection factory to FB SDK? Do you set special ports in this factory for every connection?