# "Access Token not found" when using Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, blackberry

I have a BlackBerry app which needs to post a message to a user's Facebook wall. I am using the [Facebook BlackBerry SDK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/).

I have set up a simple test app which attempts to get the current user's details when a button is pressed by calling the following method:

```
private void postToFacebookWall(){

    String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
    String APPLICATION_ID = "xxx"; //Removed for security
    String APPLICATION_SECRET = "xxx"; //Removed for security
    String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.USER_DATA_PERMISSIONS;

    ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
    Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);

    try {

        User user = fb.getCurrentUser();
        Logger.log("User has authenticated app and logged in. Name: "+user.getName());

    } catch (FacebookException e) {

        Logger.log(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Here's what happens when I click the button.

In the system log I receive an error message: Access Token not found.

Then the following login screen is shown:

[image]

Then I'm asked whether I would like to authenticate this app:

[image]

Clicking on 'Install' or 'Cancel' does nothing.

If I log into Facebook via the website and authenticate the app then I don't get the 'Access Token not found' error and everything works as expected.

How can I allow my Facebook app to be authenticated correctly to avoid the 'Access Token not found' error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually any BB app with same approach can't authorize right now. It is FB issue, but no one is hurry to fix it.

1. Here is mine question:
   [Unable to pass FB OAuth for my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395874/unable-to-pass-fb-oauth-for-my-application)
2. Here is FB bug ticket:
   https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/401534949883394?browse=search_4ffad6fdebcfa6990918340
3. Here is topic on dev forum:
   http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/FaceBook-API-error-code-11-Method-Deprecated/m-p/1808833#M203977

I found workaround to pass it but it doesn't work for all OSes/devices. Use iPhone user agent **"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16"** and enable cookies in `BrowserField`.

Please mark FB issue as **reproduced**. So probably they will increase priority and fix it faster.

UPDATE: FB fixed the issue! Please verify!

Comment: Many thanks for this, saved me tearing my hair out thinking it was something at my end. Surprised that Facebook don't treat this as a priority - I mean BlackBerry may not be that popular right now but we're still talking about millions of devices worldwide.

Comment: I think they don't realize it. Because to reproduce it you have to remove authorized app from list of your apps in FB profile. It's issue for all new users for app but not for existing.

Comment: Could you flag FB bug as reproduced?

Comment: How do I do that? When I go to the bug ticket page I can't see anywhere to flag it.

Comment: If you're FB developer you will see additional buttons like subscribe and reproduced. You could also comment on the issue. So login to FB with you FB developer account and open ticket issue after.

Comment: Still not fixed for me. Getting "Access Token not found" and screen permanently fixed on "Connecting to Facebook"

Comment: I think "Access Token not found" is correct message from log since first time you don't have it. As soon as you finished login/authorization with FB (Press "Install" on permissions page) you will be OK.

Comment: Cleaned the simulator and everything started working, thanks for your help!